# having problem with flutter and dart environment variables

Tags: flutter, git, dart

i can use flutter command without putting git in the variable environment. but when I run dart command it gives this error "Unable to find Git in your PATH", and if I put git in the variable environment. both doesn't work but git commands work.

i want to be able to run both dart and flutter commands

Comment: where is your flutter folder and what line did you pasted in env var?

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76884682/7976758