# Dart and flutter error Unable to find git in your PATH

Tags: flutter, git, dart, android-studio

Dart and flutter error Unable to find git in your PATH.
This problem is starting to bother me
When I order Flutter Doctor this error appears
In some cases, the error does not appear here, but it always appears when I write
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

It used to work before without any problems.

I checked environment variables I think it's fine
But when the problem is solved with Flutter it is not solved with Dart

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76823155/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh Boy, I had some hours of fun because of this one.

First, make sure you have git installed, and the Path is correct.
You should have a link to your `<git_installation_path>\bin\git.exe` and `<git_installation_path>\cmd`, and another one to your Flutter direcctory, `<Flutter_path>\bin`.

If you still have issues launching Flutter commands from your terminal, or from a terminal in Visual Studio Code, you can try opening the folder of your project and running this command:

```
git config --global safe.directory *
```

You might need to restart your terminal or your VSC in order to the changes to take effect